What is Catholic Church's official stand on the Loretto Chapel Staircase?
The staircase in Loretto Chapel in Santa Fe, New Mexico is said to have been built by St. Joseph, the patron saint of carpenters.
According to the story, the Sisters of Loretto prayed to St. Joseph for nine days to help them find a builder for a staircase. On the last day, a man appeared with a donkey and toolbox and offered to build the staircase. He worked alone using only hand tools and disappeared without being paid or identified. The Sisters believed the man was St. Joseph himself.
The staircase is a helix-shaped spiral that stands 20 feet tall and has two 360-degree turns. It was built without nails, only wooden pegs, and has no visible means of support. The staircase's design is considered innovative and baffling, and some of its design considerations remain a mystery to experts today.
My question: what is the official stand of the Catholic Church on the aforementioned staircase?
